# jQplot formatString "%n"

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I've a little problem with jQplot. I'm trying to do a DateAxisRenderer like this :
http://tinyurl.com/p8v5coh

And i've this :
http://tinyurl.com/qd2lbxh

I don't want to make a rotation on my test. I just want to input a line break between my hour and my date.

There is my code :

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [test2], {
        title:'Plot to test JQPLOT',
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outsideGrid'
        }, 

    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: 0,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },      


    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: "X Axis",
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%H %#.2f %n %#.2f %#d-%#m-%Y',
            },
            //min:'June 16, 2008 8:00AM', 
            tickInterval:'14400000',
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: "Y Axis",
            renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,  
            tickOptions: {
                angle: 0
            }
        }
    },
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 20,
    },
    cursor:{
        show: true,
        zoom: true,
        showTooltip:false
    },
    series:[{showMarker:false}],
});
```

As you can see, i've tried '%n' as it's write in the [official doc][1].
I think it's idiot, but I can't solve this problem myself. The line break doesn't work.

Can you show me the right way?

Ty

jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

Answer (score 0):

jqplot sometimes does strange things with axes and labels.  That's why I usually manually define my own axes ticks like this:

```
axes: {
            xaxis: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                label: 'Date',
                tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %Y'},
                pad: 0,
                ticks: lsTicks,
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            },
```

where `lsTicks` looks lomething like this:

```
["2014-01", "2014-02", "2014-03", "2014-04"]
```

and its length is the same as your data.  To make things more readable, you can add `tickOptions: {angle: -20},`, so that your dates come in at an angle if you have too many to fit next to each other.

`tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %Y'}` says:  display a 3 letter month, then a 4 digit year.  For more options and info, see [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html).

Alternatively, you can use `min`, `max` and `tickInterval`, but I have found that they misbehave sometimes.  See [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/date-axes.html) and [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php) for more.

Comment: ty I will try "ticks: mypersonalticks", but why %n doesn't work? I will really enjoy it

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea.  the `formatString` formatting capabilities change depending on what you are trying to do.  I assume that %n would work if you used it for legends or cursors, but I haven't tried.