# Newline character %n in jqplot.dateAxisRenderer tick format options does not work

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I am using Netbeans/JSF/Primefaces6.1 to develop a web application, in which I want to display a line chart with date/time X-Axis. I set the time format according to the following link,
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html

I want to use a new line character %n to render the date as two lines

```
2014-01-01
02:10:52
```

instead of only one line

```
2014-01-01 02:10:52
```

However, the %n does not work and the latter always renders as follows, which means the %n renders as a space and the date/times overlap.
[image]

Either I use the Primefaces DateAxis class as follows

```
private LineChartModel initLinearModel() {
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
    series.setLabel("Series 1");
    model.setExtender("lineChartExtender");
    model.addSeries(series);

    series.set("2014-01-01 00:10:50", 51);
    series.set("2014-01-06 01:10:51", 22);
    series.set("2014-01-12 02:10:52", 65);
    series.set("2014-01-18 03:10:53", 74);
    series.set("2014-01-24 04:10:54", 24);
    series.set("2014-01-30 05:10:55", 51);

    model.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
    axis.setMax("2014-02-01");
    axis.setTickFormat("%Y-%m-%d%n%H:%M:%S");
    model.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);

    return model;
}
```

or use the low-level jqPlot configuration in the extender as follows, it does not work.

```
    function lineChartExtender() {
        this.cfg.axes = {
            xaxis : {
                renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions : {
                    formatString : "%b %#d %n %H:%M:%S",
                    angle : -30
                },
                drawMajorGridlines : false
            },
            yaxis : {
                // Other Options for Y Axis
            }
        };
    }
```

So how can I let the newline character %n in jqPlot work properly?

Comment: Does it work in plain jqplot? If not, it is not PrimeFaces related

Comment: I am not familiar with jqplot, but when I invoke the javascript extender function, which seems to be the direct invocation of jqplot, as shown in my question, it still does not work.

Comment: I understand, but sometimes e.g. a newer/latest version of jsplot is easier to test 'plain'. But if it, like you suggest it is most likely not working in plain jqplot either, it is not a PrimeFaces related issue directly but certainly not a jsf one. And keep in mind that a plain `\n' (%n?) does nothing in html unless the label is 'preformatted' via css! So look how it is rendered in the source of the html and check if you can apply 'preformat' to the tick via css

Comment: Btw, a simple google gave me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26115004/jqplot-formatstring-n

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I removed `tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer` from xaxis, then the newline formats as documented.